# Particular Solution to General Solution of Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The IVP $x'=\sqrt{|x|}, x(0)=0$ has the two solutions $x=0,\frac{1}{4} t^2 sign(t)$

Im supposed to generalize the solution (i.e. Writing it in terms of $x_0,t_0$ such that the new initial condition is $x(t_0)=x_0$)

I am familiar with solving a differential equation to get a more general solution then applying the initial conditions to get the particular, but I'm not sure how to go the other way. If this was an exponential i might have a better idea, but at this point I need a little guidance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Find the general solution to the DEQ for two cases:

- **Case 1**: For $x > 0$, we have $x' = \sqrt{x}$
- **Case 2**: For $x < 0$, we have $x' = \sqrt{-x}$

After finding the general solution, then substitute in the initial condition $x(t_0) = x_0$ to solve for the constants.